# ActiveRecord query to find attribute on related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Trying to run this ActiveRecord query, but running into a few errors. Looked at a few S.O. posts including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10150143/3096689) but no luck still...

I have a model `UserVote` and model `User`. Here is the UserVote model

```
# UserVote.rb

belongs_to :voter, class_name: 'User', touch: true
belongs_to :voteable, class_name: 'User', touch: true
```

When there is a row in the DB, I can access the voter (User) object and voteable (User) object like so.

```
# Finding the voter's name

UserVote.find(13).voter.name
=> 'User1334342`
```

However, I am trying to query all of the `UserVotes` where the `voteable` object has a `category` of `Dancer`.

Something like this:

```
UserVote.joins(:voteable).where(["voteable.category = ?", "Dancer"]).count
```

This gives me the error:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "user_votes" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "user_votes"."voteable_id" WHERE (voteable.category = 'Dancer')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "voteable"
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"voteable" is the name of your relation, but the actual table name is "users". When you are specifying your where clause with a string like that, you are actually writing sql, so you are referencing a "voteable" table, which doesn't exist. Try this instead:

```
UserVote.joins(:voteable).where(["users.category = ?", "Dancer"]).count
```

Comment: You know what's funny, I could have **sworn** I tried this. In fact I was close to putting it in my question as something I've tried. Thanks @Rob. Congrats on your first 20 points :)